# Convert Visual Studio 7.1 project to Visual Studio 9 project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I have an Asp.Net project in Visual Studio 7.1 , Now when I open it in Visual Studio 2008 , I can't access to project files :

[image]
<sub>(source: [picfront.org](http://www11.picfront.org/picture/jhdDJNjqQn/thb/vs.jpg))</sub>

How can I open the project with VS2008 or VS2010 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the sln file with a simple text editor (make backup)

and  search for your project that did not find, and correct the directory path.

You have probably a line like that... you need to fix the dir, saved it and open it again.

```
   Project("{XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX}") = "PECeShopSame", 
"Dir1\PECeShopSame\PECeShopSame.csproj", "{XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this is old post but I learned that you can also accomplish converting the .csproj file by browsing to the .csproj file and double-clicking on it.  Visual Studio will open and offer to convert it for you - follow the wizard.  As a final step in the wizard, it will prompt you to select the project in solution explorer and convert to web application.

I had situation where the files didn't appear in solution explorer after converting .csproj file therefore I couldn't select "convert to web application".  I closed the (empty) solution then opened as web site (instead of project/solution) and all was well!